# Using regular expressions to check the format of all values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to check that all the values in my dataframe have the same format and retrieve the values and corresponding column names and index for those that do not match. For example, 0.1, 0.01, 12.4, 12.44 and 1 are allowed, however, 24..2 or 60*9 are not allowed (these are some wrongly entered values I found in my dataframe).

I have tried the following:

```
value = '24..2'
df[df.eq(value1).any(1)]
```

Then, manually look for the value and corresponding column its under and replace it with the most probable correct value:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].replace("24..2", "24.2")
```

I have also tried to automate this by using findall() regular expression. It finds a list of matches, but I have not been able to find a way to return the non-matches and corresponding columns that they are under.

```
import re
for val in vals:
    found = re.findall("[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*", val)
    if found:
    print(found)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehension, such as the following *untested* example:

```
[(val, index) for val, index in enumerate(vals) if len(re.findall("[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*", val)) == 0]
```

This will create a list of tuples. Each tuple contains `val` and its index in `vals` if there are no matches. Cases where `val` does return a match will not be added to the list. You will probably have to change the snippet `len(re.findall("[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*", val)) == 0` to something else as empty matches might still return a value. It has been a little bit since iv'e used the `re` module. Either way, that snippet is what determines if the value gets added to the list.

**Update**

`re.search(pattern, string)` returns None if there is no match. So you can do:

```
if re.search(pattern, string) == None:
    # No match was found
```